# How to build a multi-histogram with a cumulative percentage line overlapped?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following dataset.

How can I display it as a histogram where bins are based on Callees, the Y axis is Caller values, and for each bin a bar for each one of the 3 distinct libraries below. Then have the cumulative % expressed as a line over growing towards a 100% value on a secondary axis on the right hand side like in the [Sample Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDwNv.jpg), except there would be one bar for each library.

```
Library                 Callees Callers Cumulative %
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar       0     238        0.314
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar       1     371        0.8034
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar       2     121        0.9631
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar       3       9        0.9749
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar       4       7        0.9842
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar       5       2        0.9868
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar       6       3        0.9908
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar       7       1        0.9921
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar       9       1        0.9934
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar      10       2        0.996
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar      11       1        0.9974
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar      12       1        0.9987
httpcore5-5.2-beta1.jar      13       1             1
httpcore5-h2-5.2-beta1.jar    0      31        0.3647
httpcore5-h2-5.2-beta1.jar    1      46        0.9059
httpcore5-h2-5.2-beta1.jar    2       7        0.9882
httpcore5-h2-5.2-beta1.jar    7       1             1
httpcore5-reactive-5.2.jar    0       7           0.7
httpcore5-reactive-5.2 .jar   1       3             1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of Chart for the dataset:
[image]

If yes, you can create the **PivotChart**- and go to **Design**- **Change Chart Type**:
[image]

Select the **Combo**- Change the **Cumulative%** to **Line the Markers** and **check** the option **Secondary Axis**:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to overlap the results for the different jar files over the same bin values? For example, in the image, the bars over bin 0, for httpcore5 and httpcore5-h2 be positioned adjacent to one another over the same tick, but have different colors?